# How to fetch Physical SQL Query from a Semantic Query in RDL file?

Tags: c#, .net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

How to fetch Physical SQL Query from a Semantic Query in RDL file?
We have some following steps to go ahead while extracting the Semantic Query from RDL

1. Extract the Semantic Query from RDL file
2. Validate against the Semantic Model XSD
3. Parse and Transfrom Semantic Query into a structure where we will be able to generate Physical SQL from
4. Execute the conversion process to get physical query

We accomplished step 1, We were able to Extract the semantic query from RDL and store it in XML

Question 1:

For step 2, Validating against the XSD. XSD path is http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/10/semanticmodeling/SemanticModeling.xsd and our XML is extracted from RDL. The Semantic Model XSD mentioned above has some import namespace to DataSourceView.XSD. Can anyone suggest how and where can I get DataSourceView.XSD?

Question 2:

For Parse and Transform the Semantic Query, do we need to create an XML parser in C# or does any API which can perform this.

We can't Run the RDL file against Reporting model, because our requirement is to get the Physical SQL not the Dataset.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to extract the SQL or convert the semantic query to SQL directly from an RDL file that contains a report model reference.

However, the **SQL is available in the [Report Server log file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156500.aspx#bkmk_view_log) after the report is generated**.