# Is there any API that allows us to convert Semantic query to SQL query?

Tags: c#, .net, api, ssrs-2008, semantics

Is there any API that allows us to convert Semantic query to SQL query? I need to extract the semantic query from RDL file and convert into sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know really know if there is any way to achiev this, and never met anny implementation of stuff like that. But like link says, there *should be* a log of Reporting Service, that shows actual SQL query.

[Fetch SQL query from RDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485871/how-to-fetch-physical-sql-query-from-a-semantic-query-in-rdl-file)

Hope this helps.